# How to insert Javascript/HTML into MediaWiki?

Tags: javascript, html, insert, mediawiki

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Adding_HTML_to_wiki_pages

```
$(function () {
    var myElement = document.getElementById('mw-mywiki-example');
    myElement.innerHTML = 'any HTML';
}());
```

This does not work for me, it displays nothing. Using MW latest version, I tried inserting Javascript and HTML this way, none worked.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: It simply doesn't display any content put under 'any HTML'

Comment: It would be great if someone could provide an example/guide for how to insert a Google Adsense ad code into a (https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CustomNavBlocks) sidebar via Common.js

Answer (score 0):

The code provided assumes there is an element with id "mw-mywiki-example" in the page. Make sure you add something like

```
<div id="mw-mywiki-example"></div>
```

Alternatively, try using the id of an existing element, such as this:

```
$(function () {
    var myElement = document.getElementById('mw-content-text');
    myElement.innerHTML = 'any HTML';
}());
```

(I just tried this at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:BlankPage, by running the code in the Browser's console, and it worked)